# PHP: Converting from UTF-8 HTML

Tags: php, html, parsing, utf-8

I have a French site that I want to parse, but am running into problems converting the (uft-8) html to latin-1.

The problem is shown in the following phpunit test case:

```
class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private static function fromHTML($str){
        return html_entity_decode($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }

    public function test1(){

        //REMOVE THE SPACE between the '&' and 'nbsp'. SO won't
        //let me write it without the space
        $strFrom    = 'Wanted& nbsp;: les Chasseurs de Tamriel';
        $strTo  = 'Wanted : les Chasseurs de Tamriel';
        $strFrom = self::fromHTML($strFrom);
        $this->assertEquals($strTo, $strFrom);
    }

    public function test2(){
        $strFrom    = 'Remplacement d&#8217;Almalexia';
        $strTo      = 'Remplacement d’Almalexia';
        $strFrom = self::fromHTML($strFrom);
        $this->assertEquals($strTo, $strFrom);
    }

    }
```

test2 completes fine. test1 seems to fail as the space isn't correct, so when converted to ascii it ends up as a unknown character (�).

How would I ensure both tests pass?

Comment: Why is there a space between the '&' and 'nbsp;'? Is that what you are trying to fix?

Comment: Because I can't write it without the space as SO converts it into a space if I don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test1` does not fail, its answer is correct. The strings you compare are not the same. “&nbsp;” is *not* decoded to a space (`0x20`). It’s a non-breaking space character and as such gets decoded to `0xa0`. When you change `strTo` to contain that character before the colon the `assertEquals` will return true. Of course you have to make sure that your file is saved with the UTF-8 encoding, just as [PERR0_HUNTER mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244739/php-converting-from-utf-8-html/1244801#1244801) but seeing that you use the “’” character you are probably already doing that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just as a small suggestion, make sure that your .php file encoding is set to utf8, you don't know how many people miss that.